# PHP include code shows one thing but browsers show another

Tags: php, include

I have a series of php includes on a web page that look like this...

```
<?php include 'folder1/file.php'; ?>
<?php include 'folder2/file.php'; ?>
<?php include 'folder3/file.php'; ?>
```

They look like the above in my code editor but when I upload to my server it views like this when I look at the source code...

```
<?php include 'folder1/file.php'; ?>
<?php include 'folder3/file.php'; ?>
<?php include 'folder3/file.php'; ?>
```

So I thought maybe the file wasn't uploading....so I changed the code to this and uploaded the page....

```
<?php include 'folder1/file.php'; ?>
<?php include 'folder3/file.php'; ?>
```

And when viewing that in any browser it viewed as expected, showing just the two includes.  Telling me that the web page is uploading properly to the server.  I've emptied my cache, refreshed the page and nothing.  So then when I change the code back to this and upload....

```
<?php include 'folder1/file.php'; ?>
<?php include 'folder2/file.php'; ?>
<?php include 'folder3/file.php'; ?>
```

It stills shows this in the live page

```
<?php include 'folder1/file.php'; ?>
<?php include 'folder3/file.php'; ?>
<?php include 'folder3/file.php'; ?>
```

I have PHP installed on the server and all other PHP codes/includes work correctly.  The following PHP code does run correctly.

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Here is the code for folder2/file.php

```
<div class="propertylistingbox" id="propertylistingbox">
  <div class="proplistingleft" id="proplistingleft"><a href="second-base/index.php"><img src="/second-base/images/FirstBase01.png" alt="Second Base Exterior" width="284" height="193" border="0" /></a>                    
    <div class="reservation-request-button"><a href="../properties-search.php"></a>
    </div>
</div>
  <div class="propertylistingmain" id="propertylistingmain">
    <div class="propheader" id="propheader">
      <h3>SECOND BASE</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="propbulletlist" id="propbulletlist">
      <ul>
        <li>Located In Oneonta, NY</li>
        <li>Accommodates 4</li>
        <li>High Speed Internet</li>
        <li>2 Bedrooms</li>
        <li>Close to 3 bedroom apartment &quot;First Base&quot;</li>
        <li>1.25 Miles to Cooperstown Baseball World</li>
        <li>2.75 Miles to Cooperstown All Star Village</li>
        <li>19 Miles to Cooperstown Dreams Park</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="propdetails" id="propdetails">
        <div class="details-button">
        <a href="second-base/index.php">Click For More Details</a>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="propspecialsbanner" id="propdetails2"></div>
    <div class="propcalendarmaplink" id="propcalendarlink"><strong><a href="second-base/index.php">CALENDAR OF AVAILABILITY</a></strong><br />
  <strong><a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=119+Chestnut+Street,+Oneonta,+NY+13820&hl=en&sll=42.454503,-75.069752&sspn=0.017447,0.046391&oq=119+CHESTNUT+STreONEONTA+NY+13820&hnear=119+Chestnut+St,+Oneonta,+Otsego,+New+York+13820&t=m&z=17" target="_new">GOOGLE MAP</a></strong></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have PHP installed on your server? And setup properly? can you run `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Comment: It sounds like there's offending code in 'folder2/file.php' can you share the contents of those files?

Comment: Thank you for your replies.  I have edited the post to include more information.

Comment: It could be your FTP client, maybe try deleting the file on the server and reuploading?

Comment: I thought the same, so I downloaded the file from the server....checked the code and it was correct.  Deleted the file from the server and uploaded the file again which had the right code...but yet it still displays as described in my post once uploaded on the live site.  Also any other changes I make and upload show up on the live site, so the FTP client seems to be working.  Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: Ok I apologize to all of you for wasting your time.  I was making a stupid mistake.  file2/file.php had been accidentally replaced with the file.php that was found in file3/file.php.  Again I apologize for wasting your time, but I do thank you for your help anyway.  Stack Overflow is full of intelligent folks, I have been reading old posts for over a year and they solved every trouble I've encountered.  Keep up the great work!